# VS 2013 Built in GIT - Branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

This is my first time using GIT so I may completely be using it wrong or misunderstanding, but in VS 2013's built in GIT version control, I create a new branch and make some changes but those changes seem to be there even when I switch back to my main branch.

Is this how it's suppose to work? I assume that changes I make in one branch would not affect another branches' code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add and commit those files, before switching branches.

Otherwise, those private (ie not versioned) files will still be there when switching branches.

[image: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2013-02-GitCreateConnectPublish/8255.GitConnectPublish10.png]

Comment: Ah gotcha thanks! Out of curiosity, is this how Git always works? Or is this just the Microsoft version of Git?

Comment: @Kevin yes, it is how Git always work: the staging area (also called "index" or "cache") is very important. You can have a quick rundown of how Git works at http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1.